# SQL Server & C# Stored Procedure & Divide by Zero Exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, stored-procedures, dividebyzeroexception

So first here is my C# code and then comes the stored procedure.

```
public DataTable GetCourseHighPass(String tmpCourse)
{
    command.Connection = OpenConnection();

    try
    {
        command.CommandText = "exec GetCourseCompletions @tmpCourse = '" + tmpCourse + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new Exception("There are no VG's for this course.");
    }
    finally
    {
        command.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

And here is my stored procedure.

```
create procedure GetCourseCompletions
   @tmpCourse nvarchar(30)
as
   select (count(pnr) * 100 / (select count(pnr) 
                               from HasStudied  
                               where courseCode = @tmpCourse 
                                 and count(pnr) =)) as VGPrecentage 
   from HasStudied 
   where grade >= 5 
     and courseCode = @tmpCourse
go
```

The problem is that if there are no students with a high pass I will get a divide by zero exception. Looking for suggestions on how to catch this exception so the program does not crash or even better to re-write the stored procedure so it does not get an exception in the first place.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Select your counts into variables in the stored procedure and, if the count is zero, return whatever you think it should return rather than performing the calculation.

Comment: This will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You should use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do what Eric said:

    `DECLARE @count int
    Set @count = (select count(pnr) from HasStudied where courseCode = @tmpCourse and count(pnr) =...)
    IF @count = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT 0 as VGPrecentage
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        select (count(pnr)*100 / @count) as VGPrecentage from HasStudied where grade >= 5 and courseCode = @tmpCourse
    END`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this kind of query instead of yours that will handle *NULL* values and *Zero* values:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN part * total <> 0 THEN part * 100 / total ELSE 0 END
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN grade > 5 THEN 1.00 ELSE 0.00 END) As part, SUM(1.00) as total
    FROM HasStudied
    WHERE courseCode = @tmpCourse) t
```